# how to add bootstrap template to ASP.net MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, templates

I want to create a ASP.net MVC5 project by using bootstrap template like this one "https://colorlib.com/polygon/metis/dashboard.html#".
I have download it by my browser but i don't know how to add it to my project in visual studio 2013.
I have not find a tuto that help to do that, i just find how to add theme.
May someone know how to do it or a tuto that can show me the way?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the source from where you downloaded this Bootstrap Bundle? Can you share the link? Looks cool

Answer (score 6):

1.- Create a new project with the MVC structure. Bootstrap and jQuery are already installed.

The folder structure should look like this:

[image: Project structure]

2.- Add your downloaded css in the Content folder

3.- Add your downloaded js in the Scripts folder

4.- Add your html files in differents view folders depending on what you want. You should put the common html elements of all the page in the _Layout page (e.g. Menu or Top bar).

Hope it helps!

Comment: You might need to update the references on the html page it should be correctly linked to the css and js files

Answer (score 0):

Create a Bootstrap class inside the Content folder and name it

```
bootstrap-anything.css
```

App Start folder contains configuration files.
The folder should contain 3 files:

```
BundleConfig.cs     
FilterConfig.cs       
RouteConfig.cs
```

Go inside BundleConfig.cs, there should be a function

```
bundes.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
"~/Content/bootstrap.css",
"~/Content/site.css"));
```

Change

```
~/Content/bootstrap.css  to   ~/Content/bootstrap-anything.css
```

That's it.